# Unsupported config option for services.logging: 'driver'

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  nodeserver:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
  logging:
    driver: awslogs
    options:
      awslogs-region: ap-south-1


version: '3.2'
services:
  nodeserver:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
  logging:
    driver: awslogs
    options:
      awslogs-region: ap-south-1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`logging` is a key on a service and not on the `services` object.

Increase the indention of your `logging` blocks by 1 layer.